# Slick orm for scala how can I retrieve a database column value

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I am new to the Slick ORM using version 3.1.1 and in the examples for plain sql I did not see how I can retrieve the value of a database column http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/sql.html . This is my simple example

```
 def listfollowing() = Action.async {


   val selectq=sql"""SELECT model,id from carsDB where id=17""".as[(String,Int)]
   // I would like to get the value of model back and put it in a Var
   // var model= model
    database.run(selectq).map {finished=> 

   // I would like to get the value of model back and put it in a Var
   // var model= model
           Ok(finished.toString())

    }
  }
```

How can I get back the value of the column model **so that I could put it in a var or val** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do: `database.run(selectq).map {finished=> ... }` `finished` is a `Vector[(String,Int)]`. If you are sure it returns just one row (because of the  `"... where id=17"`) then you can take the `headOption()` and check if there is a value in it (It would be none if there is no record with id 17) , if there is -> return it else return some error. The code would be something like this:

```
def listfollowing() = Action.async {
    val selectq = sql"""SELECT model,id from carsDB where id=17""".as[(String, Int)]
    db.run(selectq).map { finished => 
        finished.headOption match {
            case s: (String, Int) => Ok(s._1)
            case None => Ok("No car found for requested id")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)